# How to access routes folder in sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

My route.js file is becoming larger. Is there any way to split the file based on controller? 
I want to create separate route file for each folder and merge it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can do whatever you want in your project. One solution is to use the route.js file as a compilation file of your route configurations. You can write a function and execute it in place like that:

```
var routes = {};

var assemble = function() {
  //do assembling stuff here and add your routes to the routs object
}

assemble();

module.exports.routes = routes;
```

This should be enough. In your assemble function you can use some smart way to find configurations so that your code is universal and from now on whatever config you write it would get merged automatically.